# Imbalanced-Learn's FunctionSampler throws ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, imblearn

I want to use the class `FunctionSampler` from `imblearn` to create my own custom class for resampling my dataset.
 I have a one-dimensional feature Series containing paths for each subject and a label Series containing the labels for each subject. Both come from a `pd.DataFrame`. I know that I have to reshape the feature array first since it is one-dimensional. 
When I use the class `RandomUnderSampler` everything works fine, however if I pass both  the features and labels first to the `fit_resample` method of  `FunctionSampler` which then creates an instance of `RandomUnderSampler` and then calls `fit_resample` on this class, I get the following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'path_1'

Here's a minimal example producing the error:

```
import pandas as pd
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
from imblearn import FunctionSampler

# create one dimensional feature and label arrays X and y
# X has to be converted to numpy array and then reshaped. 
X = pd.Series(['path_1','path_2','path_3'])
X = X.values.reshape(-1,1)
y = pd.Series([1,0,0])
```

## FIRST METHOD (works)

```
rus = RandomUnderSampler()
X_res, y_res = rus.fit_resample(X,y)
```

## SECOND METHOD (doesn't work)

```
def resample(X, y):
    return RandomUnderSampler().fit_resample(X, y)

sampler = FunctionSampler(func=resample)
X_res, y_res = sampler.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Does anyone know what goes wrong here? It seems as the `fit_resample` method of `FunctionSampler` is not equal to the `fit_resample` method of `RandomUnderSampler`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `FunctionSampler` is correct. The problem is with your dataset.

`RandomUnderSampler` seems to work for text data as well. There is no checking using [`check_X_y`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.check_X_y.html).

But `FunctionSampler()` has this check, see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/1a08784/imblearn/base.py#L231)

```
from sklearn.utils import check_X_y

X = pd.Series(['path_1','path_2','path_2'])
X = X.values.reshape(-1,1)
y = pd.Series([1,0,0])

check_X_y(X, y)
```

This will throw an error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'path_1'

The following example would work!

```
X = pd.Series(['1','2','2'])
X = X.values.reshape(-1,1)
y = pd.Series([1,0,0])

def resample(X, y):
    return RandomUnderSampler().fit_resample(X, y)

sampler = FunctionSampler(func=resample)
X_res, y_res = sampler.fit_resample(X, y)

X_res, y_res 
# (array([[2.],
#        [1.]]), array([0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the link! As it says in the documentation of `check_X_y`:  "If the dtype of X is object, attempt converting to float, raising on failure." Since paths can't be converted to float it will throw this error. But what is the logic behind `FunctionSampler` containing `check_X_y` and `RandomUnderSampler` not? Intuitively I expect them to work the same, so either both allowing or not allowing path strings.

Comment: Valid question. I would recommend raising an issue in github.

Comment: I raised an issue!